# Sampling from mixture of *unnormalized* densities

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, mixture-distribution

Suppose I have $n$ unnormalized densities $g_1(\textbf{x}), \ldots, g_n (\textbf{x})$, for $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and $n \gg 1$, which largely overlap but in a nontrivial way. I need to sample from the mixture:
$$
f(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i f_i(\textbf{x})
$$
where $f_i(\textbf{x}) = g_i(\textbf{x}) / \int g_i(\textbf{x}^\prime) d\textbf{x}^\prime$, and for some fixed mixture weights $w_i \ge 0$, $\sum_i w_i = 1$.

Is there any sampling technique I could use, besides sampling separately (via MCMC, rejection sampling, etc.) for each $g_i$ and then combining samples according to the weights?

Due to the overlap between distributions, it seems it should be possible to do something better that exploits the overlap/similarity between $g_i$'s, but the lack of normalization seems to be a major and perhaps insormountable obstacle.

Comment: One possibility suitable in particular situations: choose a component according to weights then use rejection sampling ("accept-reject") on each of the $g_i$

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. Can you please elaborate on this? I am not sure I understand how rejection sampling would help here.

Comment: Accept-reject is often used with an unnormalized density (your $g_i$). You don't have to know the normalizing constant, you just need a suitable envelope (which in some cases is a simpler task). e.g. if $g$ is known to be log-concave this might be a feasible approach.

Comment: Glen_b's solution sounds like the only feasible solution since $f$ cannot be approximated up to a normalising constant. You therefore have to simulate from each $g_i$ or $f_i$ separately and mix the simulation by the weights $w_i$.

Comment: OK thanks. I was asking about sampling techniques that would exploit the fact that it's a mixture of overlapping unnormalized components (I'll specify it better in my question). Of course if I consider the $g_i$ separately then I can use whatever technique works for individual densities (MCMC, rejection sampling, etc.). As I was afraid, the answer is none...

Comment: It would be useful to understand more about the nature of the $f_i / g_i$, and why you think that sampling from the mixture would be easier than sampling separately. In sampling, one would often hope for the opposite scenario, i.e. some difficult target $f$ can be decomposed as a sum of simpler components, allowing for a divide-and-conquer approach to sampling.

Comment: I just came across a somewhat similar problem, namely simulating from$$f(x)\propto\sum_i \alpha_i g_i(x)$$when the $\alpha$_i's are known.